# Is it possible to say that product of positive strictly quasiconcave functions is a quasiconcave function?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have two functions $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ which are positive over a certain interval and are strictly quasiconcave. Can I say that their product $f(x)=f_1(x)f_2(x)$ is quasiconcave function? Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The function $\exp(-x^2)$ is quasiconcave, and so is $f(x) = \exp(\exp(-x^2))$, and so are $f(x-10)$ and $f(x+10)$. Note that the function $\exp(-(x-10)^2)+\exp(-(x+10)^2)$ is bimodal, and so is $g(x)=f(x-10)f(x+10)$.  So $g$ is the product of two quasiconcave functions but is itself not quasiconcave.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I think the product of two such functions can have only two local maximas. Is it right conclusion?

Comment: I'm not sure.  The sum of an increasing function and a decreasing function can have lots of oscillations, and I think analogous things like that might happen here too.